# Does This increase Randomness of a Generatored Number?

Tags: python, list, random

I am new to python programming and I wrote this code as an experiment. My question is this, does this increase the randomness of a generated number or is this just wasted of code?

```
import random

def random_number_generator():
    """ Returns a randomized random number """

    # initialize 10 variable that will have random integers from range 1-10
    r1 = random.randint(1, 10)
    r2 = random.randint(1, 10)
    r3 = random.randint(1, 10)
    r4 = random.randint(1, 10)
    r5 = random.randint(1, 10)
    r6 = random.randint(1, 10)
    r7 = random.randint(1, 10)
    r8 = random.randint(1, 10)
    r9 = random.randint(1, 10)
    r10 = random.randint(1, 10)

    # create a list that contains the 10 random integer variables
    random_lst = [r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, r10]

    # Use the random.choice() method to randomly select 1 of the 10
    # random numbers (that are randomized 1 -10)
    res = random.choice(random_lst)

    # return results
    return res


print(random_number_generator())
```

Again my question is, does this increases the randomization of a generated number or is it no more random than just applying random once? Thanks in advance for any helpful advice or info.

Comment: if you want to "increase the randomness" (whatever that means!? I'd suggest reading up on stats and cryptography to refine your question) you're better off using `random.SystemRandom().randint(1, 10)`  this will give you access to your system's CSPRNG which is much more difficult to predict (which is normally how PRNGs are judged)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the snippet & suggestion!! "increase the randomness" == "much more difficult to predict" - This is actually what I meant, thanks sir!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

short answer: no

long answer: if we assume that random.randint is a PRNG that generates numbers uniformly from the range, then it's already at maximum "randomness" (aka entropy), so you're not gonna make it any better.  In practice, unless you're doing cryptography, go ahead and make this assumption.

(If instead you know/assume that the underlying RNG is flawed, then I'm not sure.  I would assume that doing something like this would actually decrease the overall entropy, since the flaws could compound in some way?)

Comment: Just a very simplified thought: If the RNG has a period of "11 calls", then their idea makes it *worse* by always producing the same number.

Comment: Thank you for your response! That makes a lot of sense to me! Quick Question: Would studying algorithms have helped me to understand this my own question?

Comment: I think a cryptography 101 would probably have the maximum information gain (heh) to give you the knowledge here.